# How to solve equation like this?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is there any good method to solve equations like this?
$$
\begin{cases} x^2=y^2\\-6xy+10y^2=16\end{cases}
$$
From the first equation, I see:
$$
1) x=1, y=1
$$
$$
2)x=1, y=-1
$$
$$
3)x=-1, y=1
$$
$$
4)x=-1, y=-1
$$
When I plug 2) and 3) to the second equation, I see it works.

So now I have 2 solutions, but wolfram found more...
Is there any good method for equations like this?

Comment: From the first equation you just see $|x|=|y|=1$?

Comment: From the first equation you see $x = \pm y$. Plug both in the second equation and you will get the right answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the first equation we can just conclude $x=\pm y$, nothing more.

If $x=y,$ from the second equation 
 $-6(y)y+10y^2=16\implies 4y^2=16\implies y^2=4\implies  y=\pm 2$

If $x=-y, $ from the second equation
$-6(-y)y+10y^2=16\implies y^2=1\implies y=\pm 1$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you - I'll accept in 7 minutes :)

Comment: @TomDavies92, but I could not solve the $7$ minutes riddle :)

Answer (score 5):

Add the equations.

You get $x^2-6xy+9y^2=16 \implies(x-3y)^2=16 \implies (x-3y)= \pm4$.And you have $x= \pm y$ .